# Wreath product as a permutation group.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, wreath-product

I'm working through Dixon and Mortimer's book Permutation groups. I'm currently working on showing that we can turn a wreath product into a permutation group. I've changed the notation used from the book slightly as I find it easier to use but the reference is the same.

Let $G$ and $H$ act on sets $\Omega$ and $\Psi$ respectively, and let $W=H\wr G = A\rtimes G = H^{\Psi}\rtimes G$. $A$ naturally acts on $\Gamma$ the direct product of $\Psi$ with itself $|\Omega|$ times i.e. $\Gamma = \Psi^{\Omega}$. We can define an action of the wreath product $W$ on $\Gamma$ in the following way: for each $(a,g)\in W$ and $\beta\in\Gamma$ let $\beta^{a,g}:\Omega\rightarrow\Psi$ defined as:

$$\delta\mapsto \left((\delta^{g^{-1}})^{\beta}\right)^{(\delta^{g^{-1}})^{a}}.$$

My issue is showing that this is an action as taken $a,g = 1$,  I get, $\delta^{\beta(1_{A},1)}= (\delta^{\beta})^{\delta}$ which doesn't satisfy the definition of a group action. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is supposed to be the difference between a "wreath product" and a "Wreath Product"?

Comment: Apologies that was a mistake I've corrected the post now.

Comment: $\Psi^{\Omega}$ is the direct product of $\lvert\Omega\rvert$ copies of $\Psi$, not the direct product of $\lvert\Psi\rvert$ copies of $\Omega$, as you write. And the formula you give has a $b$ in it, even though there is no $b$ in the defition. Please double check what you are writing carefully.

Comment: Where in Dixon/Mortimer is this problem?

Comment: I think I've corrected my mistakes, I copied it from my notes incorrectly. It appears on page 50(using different notation, however)

Comment: $\delta$ is an element of $\Omega$. So $\delta^{g^{-1}}$ is in $\Omega$, and so you can apply $\beta$ to it to get an element of $\Psi$. You want to apply $(\delta^{g^{-1}})^a$ to this. Now, $\delta\in\Omega$, so $\delta^{g^{-1}}$ makes sense: it's an element of $\Omega$. But $a\in H^{\Psi}$. How are you leeting $a$ act on $\Omega$ so that you can calculate $(\delta^{g^{-1}})^a$?  I still don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to prove that $\beta$ defines a group action, this is the same action as in Dixon,Mortimer, but the textbook doesn't explain why its an action and I've been unable to prove it myself.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the formula you wrote does not make sense. So there is something wrong with the formula you wrote. Looking at the book, I do not think you've copied it correctly, so it's no wonder that you cannot prove it. "What you are trying to do" refers to the formula, i.e.,, how you are trying to define the action, not to your overall goal.

Comment: If we ignore my notation and use the notation of the book, I still have the same issue. I'm unable to show that $\phi^{1,1} = \phi$

Comment: Your entire set-up is messed up. If $G$ acts on $\Omega$, then $H\wr G$ should be $H^{\Omega}\rtimes G$, not $H^{\Psi}\rtimes G$. The fact that you have so many errors in how you are setting up the sets and the actions is no doubt the reason why you are unable to show that you have an action: you have the wrong things acting on the wrong sets all over the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have the correct setup.

Following Dixon and Mortimer, but switching to your notation:

Let $G$ act on $\Omega$, and $H$ act on $\Psi$. We let $A=H^{\Omega}$, and then $H\wr_{\Omega}G = A\rtimes G = H^{\Omega}\rtimes G$. (*You have it as $H^{\Psi}$, which is incorrect.*)

Since $H$ acts on $\Psi$, then $H^{\Omega}$ acts on $\Psi^{\Omega}$ "coordinatewise". (*You have $H^{\Psi}$ acting on $\Psi^{\Omega}$, which is not at all clear*). That is, given $f\colon\Omega\to \Psi$ and $h=(h_{\omega})_{\omega\in\Omega}\in H^{\Omega}$, we have
$$f^{h}(\omega) = f(\omega)^{h_{\omega}^{-1}}$$
for each $\omega\in\Omega$.

In addition, $G$ acts on $\Psi^{\Omega}$ by acting on the coordinates; that is, given $f\colon\Omega\to\Psi$, and $g\in G$, we have
$$(f^g)(\omega) = f(\omega^{g^{-1}}).$$

So now we want to let $A\rtimes G = H^{\Omega}\rtimes G = H\wr_{\Omega} G$ act on $\Psi^{\Omega}$. We define it as follows:

> Given $\beta\in \Psi^{\Omega}$ (so we think of $\beta$ as a function $\beta\colon\Omega\to\Psi$), and $(a,g)\in A\rtimes G = H\wr_{\Omega} G$, we let $\beta^{(a,g)}\colon \Omega\to\Psi$ be defined by
> $$\beta^{(a,g)}(\omega) = \Bigl( \beta(\omega^{g^{-1}})\Bigr)^{\left(\omega^{g^{-1}}\right)^a} = 
> \beta^{(a,g)}(\omega) = \Bigl( \beta(\omega^{g^{-1}})\Bigr)^{a(\omega^{g^{-1}})}.$$

With this definition, what happens when $(a,g)=(1_A,e_G)$?
Note that $A=H^{\Omega}$, so $1_A$ is the map that sends every $\omega\in\Omega$ to $e_H\in H$.  So we have:
$$\begin{align*}
\beta^{(1_A,e_G)}(\omega) &= \Bigl( \beta(\omega^{e_G})\Bigr)^{1_A(\omega^{e_G})}\\
&= \Bigl( \beta(\omega)\Bigr)^{1_A(\omega)}\\
&= \Bigl(\beta(\omega)\Bigr)^{e_H}\\
&= \beta(\omega),
\end{align*}$$
because by definition $e_H$ acts trivially on $\Psi$. Thus, $\beta^{(1_A,e_G)}=\beta$, as expected.

I *suspect* you may have mistakenly evaluated $(\delta)^{1_A}$ as $\delta$ (that seems to match your computation?); but as noted above, since $A=H^{\Omega}$, then the identity of $A$ is the map that sends every $\delta$ to $e$, not the identity map of $\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you for this, it's cleared up my issue, I've changed my variables that much whilst writing I appear to of crossed them over at some point. The very last section, I had certainly had miss evaluated $(\delta)^{1_{A}}, which was what was causing me most of my issues.  Thanks again for helping me out! I really appreciate tit!